# NSTask and STPrivileged Task die after a while

Tags: objective-c, macos, swift

I'm trying to run a long running task with STPrivilegedTask.
It starts fine and work for like 2 minutes. But then it just stops execution (Compared to running directly from terminal).
Here's the code (Swift)

```
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName(NSFileHandleDataAvailableNotification , object: nil, queue: nil, usingBlock: { note in
        var data = note.object?.availableData
        let output = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        self.logText.stringValue = self.logText.stringValue + " \n " + output!

    })

    let task = STPrivilegedTask()
    task.setLaunchPath("/bin/sh")
    task.setArguments(["-c", cmd]);
    task.launch()
    task.waitUntilExit()
    task.outputFileHandle().waitForDataInBackgroundAndNotify()
```

the command itself is something like this:

```
/Users/alexandrius/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Recover-fczfhpkdplwbujelgmwhirjcesxk/Build/Products/Debug/Recover.app/Contents/Resources/foremost -i /dev/disk2 -o /Users/alexandrius/RECOVER/req -v
```

*foremost is file recovery software, I'm trying to make gui for it

With or without waitUntilExit method the result is same.